# What algorithm a RowSorter use for sorting a JTable rows?

Tags: swing, algorithm, sorting, jtable

There are many sorting algorithms e.g. bubble sort, insertion sort, merge sort etc. When sorting rows of JTable what algorithm is used? anybody please.

Comment: @Sarz There is a class TableRowSorter which can be added to a JTable and you don't have to do anything else just click on table header and it will sort the table data. Tell me in this default scenario what alogo is used???

Comment: `TableRowSorter` uses comparator for sorting, try to search, or read [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/263747/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/sorting-algorithm-comparator-comparable), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/#sorting)

Comment: @Sarz- Please explain "It wil get sorted if you arrange sorted data somehow"

Comment: Sorry the links in the answer below are not useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>`Dual-Pivot Quicksort`</del> has been used by `Arrays.sort(...)` since Java 1.7.0:

```
//@see javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter#sort()
private Row[] viewToModel;
public void sort() {
  //...
  // sort them
  Arrays.sort(viewToModel);
```

---

**Edit**

Sorry I missed, `Arrays.sort(int[])` not using:

```
public static void sort(int[] a) {
    DualPivotQuicksort.sort(a, 0, a.length - 1, null, 0, 0);
}
```

correct:

```
public static void sort(Object[] a) {
    if (LegacyMergeSort.userRequested)
        legacyMergeSort(a);
    else
        ComparableTimSort.sort(a, 0, a.length, null, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: @Nadeem I misunderstood. Please see the `java.util.Arrays.java` sourcecode direct...